# Button Column Duplicates when datagridview is populated from mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm creating a program that will open a specific file from a file path. The file path is stored in a mysql database. I have a total of 6 columns. The first five columns are from mysql database and the last is the button column which is hard coded in the `Form_Load` method. when im not including the `load_data` sub the button cant find the file path.

In the first press of the button, the file opens, but when I press another button the button column duplicates and gives me an error. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub load_data()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()


    MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=password;database=ordinanceviewerdb"

    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataset As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String

        Query = "select * from ordinanceviewerdb.ordinancetbl"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
        SDA.Fill(dbDataset)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataset
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataset)

        MySqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try

    Me.DataGridView1.Columns("filepath").Visible = True

    Dim openbtn As DataGridViewButtonColumn = New DataGridViewButtonColumn
    openbtn = New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    openbtn.HeaderText = "View"
    openbtn.Text = "Open File"
    openbtn.Name = "opnbtn"
    openbtn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True

    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(openbtn)

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick


    load_data()

    Dim filename As String = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()

    If e.ColumnIndex = 5 AndAlso File.Exists(filename) Then

        Process.Start(filename)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well.. Why wouldn't it duplicate? Every time you click, you call `load_data()` and every time that sub runs you add a new column...

Comment: can you suggest me a fix? when i dont include load_data the file path cant be obtained by the button

Comment: Do a check on the final column to see if it matches by Text/Name/Tag before adding a new one? Have a flag that you can set when you run `load_data()` the first time and check it the subsequent times?

Comment: can you provide sample codes in it? im just new in programming. just a little :)

Comment: i dont have my computer right now. do you mean that i should create a condition that if mydatagridview contains the column with button then i should not load another button column on it?